# How do i call a shell app from SQL storedprocedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Im trying to call a notepad or calculator from a stored procedure. can anyone help?

Comment: Can you give us some context on why you would want to do this? Perhaps there is another (better) way to accomplish the underlying task.

Answer (score 2):

For what database will this be?

For MySql you can write a UDF (User Defined Function - See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-udf.html) to to this or use the ready made one from the UDF repository guys. See http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/index.php. See the sys_exec function and also the section labelled 'A Note of Caution' ;-)

For Microsoft SQL see the **xp_cmdshell** command here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

maybe `xp_cmdshell`  be useful for you.

> Executes a given command string as an
>   operating-system command shell and
>   returns any output as rows of text.
>   Grants nonadministrative users
>   permissions to execute xp_cmdshell.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do it in Oracle's PL/SQL as well.
Google:
Oracle "External Procedures" or start here:

[Oracle External Procedures](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_ex.htm)

You end up calling to SHELL32.DLL and telling it to open Notepad.